# SilverStripe - limiting the number of many relations a dataobject can have

Tags: silverstripe

If I have a `$has_many` relationship that I want to manage with a `GridField` in the cms, how would I go about putting a limit on the number of how many relations one object can have? Is this possible?

Can I do this in the model or would it have to be a check I add into the `GridField` I'm using to add and remove relations?

I'm looking at implementing `GridField_SaveHandler` to make a custom `GridFieldComponent` but not sure how I can use this to abort the save if i detect something is wrong.

Comment: Could you not just use `$this->MyRelationName()->Count()` to check how many already exist and if the limit is reached just remove the `GridFieldAddNewButton` from the `GridFieldConfig` in `getCMSFields()`? You can also add an extra check in the `onBeforeWrite()` hook....

Comment: Yes i've just tried that actually, the only issue there is because the page doesn't reload on actions if I add a nineth object the button still appears but doesnt work properly, and then when i refresh the page and remove the 9th item the button is still hidden until the page is refreshed

Comment: Hi, have you had a workaround yet? I am stuck here as you. Deleting the relation doesn't enforce browser to reload so the hidden "Add new" button won't appear until you refresh the page.

Comment: In the end I went with a `count()` of the relationships to trigger adding a `GridFieldAddExistingAutocompleter` component only if the limit had not been met, as described above, with the side effects also described above.

I'm thinking potentially you could add in some js to show/hide the element that is being hidden via this check, I never took it that far as for me it is a fairly minor thing the limit is for.

If you come up with a better solution, please post it here as I would like to see it :)

Comment: oh, I didn't notice you already fixed it, just saw that comment now, my answer is basically what you did already with a code example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following 2 solutions are not the cleanest way to solve this, but the most pragmatic and easiest to implement.

basically, what I suggest to do, is just count the objects and remove the ability to add new records once the count is above a certain number.

if you want to limit the number of records on a single relation/grid (lets say max 5 players per team):

```
class Player extends Dataobject {
    private static $db = array('Title' => 'Varchar');
    private static $has_one = array('TeamPage' => 'TeamPage');
}
class TeamPage extends Page {
    private static $has_one = array('Players' => 'Player');
    public function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
        $config = GridFieldConfig_RecordEditor::create();
        if ($this->Players()->count > 5) {
            // remove the buttons if we don't want to allow more records to be added/created
            $config->removeComponentsByType('GridFieldAddNewButton');
            $config->removeComponentsByType('GridFieldAddExistingAutocompleter');
        }
        $grid = GridField::create('Players', 'Players on this Team', $this->Players(), $config);
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', $grid);
        return $fields;
    }
}
```

---

if you want to limit the total number of records globally (if we limit this way to 5, this means if 1 Team already has 3 Players, then the 2nd team can only have 2):

```
class Player extends Dataobject {
    private static $db = array('Title' => 'Varchar');
    private static $has_one = array('TeamPage' => 'TeamPage');
    public function canCreate($member = null) {
        if (Player::get()->count() > 5) {
           return false;
        }
        return parent::canCreate($member);
    }
}
class TeamPage extends Page {
    private static $has_one = array('Players' => 'Player');
    public function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
        $config = GridFieldConfig_RecordEditor::create();
        $grid = GridField::create('Players', 'Players on this Team', $this->Players(), $config);
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', $grid);
        return $fields;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes this is how my site looks (the first one), even though this isn't perfect I will accept it as I think this is the closest you can get to what I am after... is there no way possibly of doing this check but with javascript and ajax? so the check is an ajax call and the js can hide the element if required...

Answer (score 1):

I have wrote a quick jQuery plugin to limit the number of items a GridField can have: -

Download the plugin here: - [gridfieldlimit.js](https://letscrate.com/f/monkeyben/silverstripe/gridfieldlimit.js)

https://letscrate.com/f/monkeyben/silverstripe/gridfieldlimit.js

**Set up the plugin in the getCMSFields function: -**

```
// Pass GridField configs, each one containing field name and item limit
$vars = array(
    "GridFieldLimits" => "[['GRIDFIELD_NAME_1', 3], ['GRIDFIELD_NAME_2', 6]]",
);

// Load the jquery gridfield plugin
Requirements::javascriptTemplate("themes/YOUR_THEME_NAME/javascript/gridfieldlimit.js", $vars);
```

Answer (score 0):

works for me: make the `canCreate` method of the DataObject that's managed by your GridField check for existing objects.

of course, this doesn't allow you to implement a customg GridFieldComponent, as you need to modify the DataObject code.

Comment: This is for creating a relationship though, not actually creating an object