# SilverStripe limit DataObject records

Tags: php, silverstripe

What's the best way to limit the amount of records a DataObject can have?

I came up with a solution by counting the records inside `canCreate` and return false when `Item::get()->count() > 5`. But it seems strange to use permissions for that reason, besides I believe it doesn't affect admins.

Comment: canCreate() also affects admin users. I do it the same way like you, but perhaps some one knows a better/other way.

Comment: @csy_dot_io return true if user is Admin or has a special permission or if there are less than $limit items...

Comment: @wmk what does that have to do with the question?

Comment: Why wouldn't the canCreate be correct on this? The method name is so generic so the reason on preventing could be anything. If the method you are overriding was canCreateIfInCorrectUserGroup() then it could lead to wrong assumptions on why it was prevented :)

Comment: But there are two nice possibilities on this: canCreate or hide the add new button: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19005633/silverstripe-limiting-the-number-of-many-relations-a-dataobject-can-have

Comment: canCreate **does** affect admins in contrary to my initial assumption, still I'm wondering if there is a cleaner solution, but I don't think there is one. The cms doesn't come with a standard feature for this

Comment: Using permissions is perfectly suits here. You controller should check whether current CMS user can CRUD the item. Pages controller and `GridField` do this out of the box. However scaffolding of the `GridField` does not check for edit permission to fallback to `GridFieldConfig_RecordViewer`.